# How to test the below api in test class?

Tags: spring-test

I have the controller class like the below with the method I need to test:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/offers")
public class OffersControllerV1 {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OffersControllerV1.class);

    // ...

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> getAllNewOffers(Pageable pageable) {
        List<OfferResponseInfo> offersList = null;
        ApiResponse response = null;
        try {
             offersList = offerFinderService.getAllNewOffers(pageable);
             response = ApiResponse.ofSuccess(offersList, "All offers fetched successfully");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            response = ApiResponse.ofFailure("Failed to fetch offers. Please try again");
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.valueOf(response.getCode()));
    }

}
```

The test case for the controller class is as below. I am trying to test method getAllNewOffers but getting response status 404. Also I am trying to invoke configuration class but it is never invoked.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {PageableConfig.class, SortParamConfig.class})
public class OffersControllerV1Test {

   protected MockMvc mvc;

   @Autowired
   WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
   }

   @Test
   public void evaluatesValidSortParameters_getAllNewOffers() throws Exception {
        int status = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/v1/offers/all")
                .param("page", "5")
                .param("size", "10")
                .param("sort", "publishedDate,asc")
                .param("sort", "createdDate,desc"))
                .andReturn().getResponse().getStatus();

        ArgumentCaptor<Pageable> pageableCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Pageable.class);
        verify(offerFinderService).getAllNewOffers(pageableCaptor.capture());
        PageRequest pageable = (PageRequest) pageableCaptor.getValue();

        assertEquals(5, pageable.getPageNumber());
        assertEquals(10, pageable.getPageSize());
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add the code for `PageableConfig` and `SortParamConfig`?

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted it out. I was missing @WebMvcTest(controllers = controller.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false) annotations.